# Writing a LLVM transformation pass to inject delays at the beginning of each function

Tags: llvm, llvm-clang, llvm-ir

I am new to LLVM, I am trying to write an LLVM transformation pass that will inject a delay to the beginning of each called function at run time.

I found the following code that injects a printf statement to the beginning of each function.

How can i change the code accordingly to inject a delay instead of the printf? (I am using LLVM 10.)

Below is the code:

```
bool InjectFuncCall::runOnModule(Module &M) {
  bool InsertedAtLeastOnePrintf = false;

  auto &CTX = M.getContext();
  PointerType *PrintfArgTy = PointerType::getUnqual(Type::getInt8Ty(CTX));

  // STEP 1: Inject the declaration of printf
  // ----------------------------------------
  // Create (or _get_ in cases where it's already available) the following
  // declaration in the IR module:
  //    declare i32 @printf(i8*, ...)
  // It corresponds to the following C declaration:
  //    int printf(char *, ...)
  FunctionType *PrintfTy = FunctionType::get(
      IntegerType::getInt32Ty(CTX),
      PrintfArgTy,
      /*IsVarArgs=*/true);

  FunctionCallee Printf = M.getOrInsertFunction("printf", PrintfTy);

  // Set attributes as per inferLibFuncAttributes in BuildLibCalls.cpp
  Function *PrintfF = dyn_cast<Function>(Printf.getCallee());
  PrintfF->setDoesNotThrow();
  PrintfF->addParamAttr(0, Attribute::NoCapture);
  PrintfF->addParamAttr(0, Attribute::ReadOnly);


  // STEP 2: Inject a global variable that will hold the printf format string
  // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  llvm::Constant *PrintfFormatStr = llvm::ConstantDataArray::getString(
      CTX, "(llvm-tutor) Hello from: %s\n(llvm-tutor)   number of arguments: %d\n");

  Constant *PrintfFormatStrVar =
      M.getOrInsertGlobal("PrintfFormatStr", PrintfFormatStr->getType());
  dyn_cast<GlobalVariable>(PrintfFormatStrVar)->setInitializer(PrintfFormatStr);

  // STEP 3: For each function in the module, inject a call to printf
  // ----------------------------------------------------------------
  for (auto &F : M) {
    if (F.isDeclaration())
      continue;

    // Get an IR builder. Sets the insertion point to the top of the function
    IRBuilder<> Builder(&*F.getEntryBlock().getFirstInsertionPt());

    // Inject a global variable that contains the function name
    auto FuncName = Builder.CreateGlobalStringPtr(F.getName());

    // Printf requires i8*, but PrintfFormatStrVar is an array: [n x i8]. Add
    // a cast: [n x i8] -> i8*
    llvm::Value *FormatStrPtr =
        Builder.CreatePointerCast(PrintfFormatStrVar, PrintfArgTy, "formatStr");

    // The following is visible only if you pass -debug on the command line
    // *and* you have an assert build.
    LLVM_DEBUG(dbgs() << " Injecting call to printf inside " << F.getName()
                      << "\n");

    // Finally, inject a call to printf
    Builder.CreateCall(
        Printf, {FormatStrPtr, FuncName, Builder.getInt32(F.arg_size())});

    InsertedAtLeastOnePrintf = true;
  }

  return InsertedAtLeastOnePrintf;
}
```

Also it would be great if there are links for good LLVM tutorials for beginners.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to declare the `delay` function the same way you declared `printf` except you'll want to change the argument type from `i8*` to `i32`. For the tutorials you could check these out
[https://anoopsarkar.github.io/compilers-class/llvm-practice.html\](https://anoopsarkar.github.io/compilers-class/llvm-practice.html%5C)

https://www.usna.edu/Users/cs/wcbrown/courses/F19SI413/lab/l13/lab.html

https://osterlund.xyz/posts/2017-11-28-LLVM-pass.html

Comment: How do i actually do that? I don't see any declaration of printf in the code above?

Comment: It's prototype is constructed at the line with the call to `FunctionType::get` and declared at the line with the call to `M.getOrInsertFunction`

Comment: If possible, can you elaborate more on how the new code will look like, i tried changing the declaration and arguments but couldn't get it to work?